# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Show the current visitor's username
        if let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["username"] as? String {
            self.userNameLabel?.text = "@" + pUserName
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login")
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }

    }
    @IBAction func commentAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CommentSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "CommentSegue"{

            let summaryView = segue.destinationViewController as? TableViewController

        }

    }

   }
```

The error I get is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier
>   "UIViewController-tCJ-qt-q4b" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a
>   UITableView.'

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The controller you created is a `UITableViewController` or subclass of one.  The error is telling you that the top-level view of that controller is not a `UITableView`.

You need to either fix the view controller's link in the storyboard or else change the controller to some other class.

Comment: I removed the TableViewDelegate subclass, and Im trying to connect the commentAction button to a tableview and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Your comment doesn't sound as if you did either of the things I suggested.  I'm not surprised you're still getting the error.